# Cannot step into a method returning IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a method that returns an IEnumerable like this..

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Page> ToPages(){
  // foreach logic
  yield return pages;

  // more foreach logic
  yield return otherPages;

  // etc
}
```

The method seems to work ... in a way. But what's really baffling is that I cannot step into it! I place debugger points all around, and the debugger just passes right through them!!!

Does anyone know why this might occur?

Comment: A note - this may be the reason you are getting a "Stepping over non-user code" message that doesn't seem to make any sense. Took  me a while to find this question when looking for that string.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The method isn't run until you enumerate into it.

```
foo.ToPages().ToList() // will enumerate and your breakpoint will be hit.
```

Comment: This is a solid answer.  IEnumerable<> always implies lazy execution.  That's one of the core differences between working with say an IEnumerable<T> vs a List<T>.  The IEnumerable flavor will just return instructions for iteration when the time comes.  List will actually walk the collection and produce results immediately.

Comment: That worked... but that is just beyond strange. Why does it behave this way?

Comment: @Ciel: I'll post some links to articles explaining why it works this way.

Comment: @Eric Lippert, thanks.  I was adding some resources but I ran out of battery.

Answer (score 9):

As others have noted, the body of an iterator block is not executed until the iterator is actually *moved*. Just creating the iterator does nothing other than creating it. People often find this confusing.

If the design and implementation of iterator blocks interests you, here are some good articles on the subject:

Raymond Chen: (short introduction to the basic points)

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080812-00/?p=21273
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080813-00/?p=21253
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080814-00/?p=21243

Jon Skeet: (long, in depth)

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx

Eric Lippert (me): (advanced scenarios and corner cases)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/iterators/

Answer (score 5):

Your enumerable method will only execute once you actually try to access the members.

This is called "**Deferred Execution**" (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx)

Try actually accessing the IEnumerable which is returned, or just call;

```
var p = obj.ToPages().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a break on the yield. That should fix it.

Comment: What do you mean? I have put breakpoints on every single line in the entire method and it still never steps into it.

Comment: the "yield" is the point at which the function returns, it should break on that.

Comment: It should, yes. But it isn't.

Comment: The yield is the point at which *the call to MoveNext* returns. If there is no call to MoveNext then the breakpoint inside it obviously will not be hit.