# C# Web API - ADO.NET in .NET Core data collection not returning and does not step through on breakpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, ado.net-entity-data-model

Good day!

I am having a hard time returning data collection with existing data (SQL Server 2012) on .Net Core ADO.NET Entity Model. Also, it does not step through breakpoint on my **Ienumerable<>Get()** but the breakpoint crosses through **public string Get(int id)**. How is it possible to cross through breakpoint on IEnumerable? I also tried following this link [Cannot step into a method returning IEnumerable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705927/cannot-step-into-a-method-returning-ienumerablet) , adding ".ToList()" on my code but it still does not cross on breakpoint. :( I have no error on my code.

Here is my code :

My ADO.NET Entity Model

```
namespace EmployeeDataAccess
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class tbl_employee
    {
        public long emp_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> group_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> company_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> RC_id { get; set; }
        public string emp_globalno { get; set; }
        public string emp_siteno { get; set; }
        public string emp_prefix { get; set; }
        public string emp_lastname { get; set; }
        public string emp_firstname { get; set; }
        public string emp_middlename { get; set; }
        public string emp_suffix { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]

My IEnumerable code (does not cross on breakpoint):

```
// GET api/values
[HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<tbl_employee> Get()
    {
        List<EmployeeEntities> EmployeesList = new List<EmployeeEntities>();
        var empTable = new tbl_employee();
        var temp = empTable.emp_firstname.ToString();

        var employeelist = (from Employees in EmployeesList 
                            select new tbl_employee
                            { emp_firstname = empTable.emp_firstname }).ToList();
        return employeelist;


    }
```

Screenshot on trying to return IEnumerable :

[image]

My Get(id) code (crosses on breakpoint) :

```
// GET api/values/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "value 1, value 2, value 3";
}
```

Screenshot on returning Get(ID) :

[image]

Will gladly appreciate any suggestions, comments, replies.

Thank you very much and have a nice day!

**(UPDATE)**

I tried reverting to the default static **IEnumerable<>Get()** and it crosses the breakpoint and returns json values. How do I do this with returning existing data on SQL Server 2012 db using ADO.NET? Thanks.

The default code I reverted back :

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2", "value3" };
}
```

Screenshot on the result :

[image]

Comment: What does your WebApiConfig.cs look like? Since you have multiple HTTP GET requests in your API, you might need to modify your Routes - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12185249/1169644) answer to the question [Single controller with multiple GET methods in ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499794/single-controller-with-multiple-get-methods-in-asp-net-web-api).

Comment: hi sir @Poosh! first of all thank you for your response. I tried adding the routes but it's still the same :( Also, I tried reverting to the default static IEnumerable and it crosses the breakpoint now and returns a result. How do I do this in returning existing data on my SQL Server database? Thanks Sir!

Comment: trying throwing exception in `Get()` function and see what happens. Also clean solution and then try running it. It should return null as you should not have anything in `EmployeeList` list.